# Set NuGet package target framework

Tags: c#, package, nuget, .net-assembly

I'm trying to set a target framework for my NuGet package with NuGet Package Explorer. I've created a folder `lib/net462/myassembly.dll`. I want to prevent the package from being installed on .NET projects targeted lower than version 4.6.2. When I install the package in a .NET 4.5.2 project, no error is thrown and the dll is installed in the project.

How can I prevent my package from being installed in a .NET project targeted lower than version 4.6.2?

See screenshot below:

[image: NuGet Package Explorer]

Comment: Looks fine to me. Do you have another cached version of that NuGet package which has a different lib folder that is being found instead?

Comment: @MattWard No I haven't. I have no clue how to solve this problem.